# Why does the equation hold?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, pseudo-differential-operators

Why is $$\exp(i\tau\Delta/4\pi)(xp)=x\exp(i\tau\Delta/4\pi)(p)+i\tau \exp(i\tau\Delta/4\pi)(p')/2\pi, $$ where $p$ is a polynomial. $\Delta$ denotes the Laplacian operator. I do not understand the equation. For example for $x=0$, $p$ a polynomial, it says $1=i\tau \exp(i\tau\Delta/4\pi)(p')/2\pi.$

Here $\tau$ is in the upper half plane, $p=p(x),$ $p'$ denotes the derivative of $p,$ and 
$$\Delta=\sum_j\frac{d^2}{dx_j^2}. $$

Comment: You're exponentiating an operator. The result is another operator. This sort of thing happens all the time. You can exponentiate a matrix (relatively straight-forward operator), e.g., by computing eigenvalues and eigenvectors, though that's not the only way.

Comment: Does $p'$ mean the derivative? And is $p$ a function of $x$ only? What is $\tau?$

Comment: $\tau \in \mathbb{H}$, $p$ is a function of $x$ . I think $p'$ denotes the derivative of $p$.

Comment: And what is $\mathbb{H}?$

Comment: So then $\Delta=\partial_{xx}?$ Or just $\Delta=\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}?$

Comment: Where does the equation come from?

Comment: By the way, the questions I'm asking here are about information that you really should fold back into the question. Otherwise, your question is likely to close due to lack of context.

Comment: If you are willing to forget some rigor (about the actual definition of $\exp(i \tau\Delta/4\pi)$) and just compute, the equation is fairly straightforward if you remember $\exp(i \tau \Delta/4\pi) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{n!} (i \tau \Delta / 4\pi)^n $ and just apply the product rule for differentiation.

Comment: $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper half plane, $\Delta=\sum_{j}\frac{d^2}{dx_j^2}$

Comment: See my edited solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will look at the 1D case. As $p$ is a polynomial, we will try exponentiating via a power series, since eventually all terms become zero. First of all, note that higher-order derivatives of a product follow the Leibniz rule:
$$(fg)^{(n)}=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}f^{(j)}g^{(n-j)}.$$
If $f(x)=x,$ as we have here, then we get some simplifications, since second-order and higher derivatives vanish:
$$(xp)^{(n)}=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}x^{(j)}p^{(n-j)}=xp^{(n)}+np^{(n-1)}.$$
So that's one piece. Next, we note, as Willie Wong has already mentioned in a comment, that
$$e^x=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{x^j}{j!}.$$
It follows that
$$\exp\left(\frac{i\tau\partial^2}{4\pi}\right)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\dfrac{i\tau\partial^2}{4\pi}\right)^{\!j}}{j!}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(i\tau)^j \partial^{2j}}{j!(4\pi)^j}, $$
but many of these terms will vanish. Let $n$ be the order of the polynomial $p$. A derivative of order $n+1$ annihilates $p$. So in the operator expansion, terms of order $n+1$ and higher will vanish. We can hence write
\begin{align*}
\left[\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(i\tau)^j \partial^{2j}}{j!(4\pi)^j}\right]\!(xp) &=\left[\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(i\tau)^j \partial^{2j}}{j!(4\pi)^j}(xp)\right]\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(i\tau)^j}{j!(4\pi)^j}\left(xp^{(2j)}+(2j)p^{(2j-1)}\right)\\
&=x\sum_{j=0}^{\lceil n/2\rceil+2}\frac{(i\tau)^j}{j!(4\pi)^j}p^{(2j)}+2\sum_{j=1}^{\lceil n/2\rceil+2}\frac{(i\tau)^j}{(j-1)!(4\pi)^j}p^{(2j-1)}\\
&=x\sum_{j=0}^{\lceil n/2\rceil+2}\frac{(i\tau)^j}{j!(4\pi)^j}p^{(2j)}+2\sum_{k=0}^{\lceil n/2\rceil+2}\frac{(i\tau)^{k+1}}{k!(4\pi)^{k+1}}p^{(2k+1)}\\
&=x\left[\sum_{j=0}^{\lceil n/2\rceil+2}\frac{(i\tau)^j \partial^{2j}}{j!(4\pi)^j}\right]\!p+\frac{i\tau}{2\pi}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\lceil n/2\rceil+2}\frac{(i\tau)^k \partial^{2k}}{k!(4\pi)^k}\right]\!p'.
\end{align*}
The exact upper limit on the sums is unimportant, except that we know it is finite. Hence, rearranging sums like we have been doing is entirely justified - without worrying about convergence.

We have shown what you were trying to show.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: You're very welcome! Fun little problem.

Comment: Is there something I need to add to make my answer more complete?

Comment: I understand almost everything,but I do not  understand  the brackets in the beginning .

Comment: in the end you used square brackets .

Comment: Not sure I follow. I'm just using square brackets as parentheses, but of a different shape to enhance readability. Also, be aware that if an operator is 'multiplying' something, then it's acting on the something. So that isn't always regular multiplication.

Comment: Note that $\exp(it\Delta)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(it)^n}{n!}\Delta^n$ does not make immediate sense (it is unclear in which sense the right side is supposed to converge), but for a polynomial $p$, the identity $\exp(it\Delta)p=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(it)^n}{n!}\Delta^n p$ is indeed true (polynomials are analytic vectors of the Laplacian).

Comment: @MaoWao: As I mentioned in the solution, because $p$ is a polynomial, the sum does not have to be infinite. Therefore, issues of convergence are irrelevant.

Comment: I just wanted to mention that your fourth displayed equation would be clearer (and not run into these convergence issues) if you plugged in $p$ right away and not stated it as an identity for the operators.